# Performance on RemoteApp vs Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, thin-client

We are making an on-premise installation of an application using Java Swing for it's GUI.

We want to run the application on a Terminal Server (Windows 2008R2) on Thin Clients (Dell WYSE 3030 using Windows 7 Embedded).

Unfortunately, we have performance issues when running the application as a published RemoteApp on the thin clients (it runs fine on a more powerful desktop computer). The GUI lags a lot, animations that take 3 seconds to complete on a regular computer take 7 seconds and are very choppy on the TC:s and the mstsc process on the TC uses 100% of a cpu core. Therefore we are thinking about replacing the TC:s with regular desktop computers.

However, when I test running the application by logging into the desktop of the terminal server, from a TC, and run the Java application there performance is ok. The actions take around 3 seconds to complete and graphics is smooth enough.

Obviously graphics are handeled differently in a RemoteApp compared to an application on a remote desktop but perhaps it is possible to optimise the published RemoteApp to perform similarly to the application on the remote desktop.

Any tips as to how I can proceed are most welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have up to date Windows updates installed on both client and server?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long answering! Well, we might not have last weeks updates installed, since the servers are in our production enviroment and we only update after review of the updates. But I'd say we are pretty up to date.